# Invoke a doPost function of GAS in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-apps-script, triggers

I need to invoke a `doPost` function that is in the Google Apps Script side, from my code in Javascript.

I have done it using a `doGet` but there are a lot of variables that I need to pass, so a `doGet` is not the best for this.

This is the code I use for the `doGet`, it works well for a form with a few inputs, but I need to implement the logic in a bigger form.

I have to invoke the function from a button

```
<input type="button" onclick="get()" value="Go" class="btn">
```

JS:

```
function get() {
    var SCRIPT_URL = "https://script.google.com/macros/s/key/exec";           
    $.getJSON(SCRIPT_URL + "?a="+ $("#a").val(),
    { method: "populate_list" },
    function (data) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(data));
    });
};
```

In the Google Apps Script this is the doPost function I have

```
function doPost(e) {
    if (e.parameter.method=="populate_list") {
        SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getRange('F2').setValue(e.parameter.a);
    }
}
```

What I need is the equivalent of the function get() that the button calls but for the doPost, so it invokes the doPost function I have in the GAS

Comment: Have you tried `$.post()`?

Comment: Could you add a answer with the new code?See [answer]

Answer (score 1):

The Jquery $.post() works for this, I get the values from the form and pass it to the script url.

JS:

```
var v_name = $("#name").val();
$.post("https://script.google.com/macros/s/KEY/exec",
        {
            index: selectedUser,
            name: v_name,
            variableName: variableValue
        },
        function (data) {
            console.log(data.name);
        }, 'json');
```

Google Script

```
function doPost(e) {

    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

    sheet.getRange('B'+e.parameter.index + "").setValue(e.parameter.name);
}
```